# Spring boot container With truststore in Azure App Service

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I have a legacy spring boot Application that uses a common library that injects a RestTemplate which is default configured to make some HTTPS calls, Meaning it is always looking for a trust-store in the classpath. Spring boot by default needs a key store when we enable trust-store

### **Issue**

I successfully containerized and deployed this app in the App service however App service is failing with the below error

> Bad Request
> This combination of host and port requires TLS.

Most of the comments out there suggest App service containers need to run on HTTP with port 80 and not HTTPS.

**Questions**

1. Is there a way to deploy this container running HTTPS to be deployed on the App service and get a call at an endpoint?
2. How are people deploying spring boot apps in Azure app service if there is a  requirement for trust-store as in trusting the third party servers?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the detailed answers from Microsoft community

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/666261/spring-boot-container-with-truststore-in-azure-app.html

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading this correctly you are looking to do outbound SSL with a trust store. If you store your trust store certificate in Azure Key Vault you can use the Azure Key Vault Certificate Spring Boot starter to accomplish what you need.

See https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/spring/azure-spring-boot-starter-keyvault-certificates/README.md#client-side-ssl